# What changed in my Word document after exporting to PDF?

Tags: ms-word

I'm using Microsoft® Word 2019 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit.

I write a document (*.docx) and I save it, then I export it to PDF with these settings:

[image]

Then, if I close the document, Word still asks me if I want to "save the changes", but I did not perform any change to the file after exporting it.

Does Word applies some changes by itself to the document?

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums At the risk of upsetting someone: When you export to pdf, Word updates fields such as page numbers and perceives this as a change, even if nothing changes.